# Why my Bundle extras does not exist?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, firebase, bundle

I am building an app and I am using FCM notifications. When user clicks on notification I want to send him to the Fragment1(that is the name of the fragment) on Main Activity. I do that with intent.putExtra but when in Main Activity I log Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras() I have null pointer exception. Why I don't have anything in putExtra?

Here is myFireBaseMessagingService

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("OnMessage", "Received");
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Body " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);

}




private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("Asp")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

And here is MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme2);
    btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme3);
    dugme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("developeri");
            Log.d("Bravo", "Subscribed to developeri!");
        }
    });


    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    StartFragment startFragment=new StartFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.myFragment, startFragment);
    ft.commit();
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    Log.d("Bundle", "Bundle is here");
    Log.d("Extras", extras.getString("action"));
    if (extras!=null && extras.containsKey("action") && extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1")){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFragment, new Fragment1()).commit();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "IF IS HERE");

    }

}
 Button.OnClickListener  btnOnClickListener= new Button.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Fragment newFragment;
         if (view==btn1){
             newFragment =new Fragment1();

         }else if(view==btn2){
              newFragment =new Fragment2();
         }else if (view==btn3){
             newFragment =new Fragment3();
         }else{
             newFragment=new StartFragment();
         }
         FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
         transaction.commit();


     }
 };
```

}

My logcat

> 06-07 09:22:49.598 23913-23913/com.example.dev3.fragmenti
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dev3.fragmenti/com.example.dev3.fragmenti.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.dev3.fragmenti.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please provide your error message and stack-trace.

Comment: Which line is line 53 in your MainActivity?

Comment: Log.d("Extras", extras.getString("action"));

Comment: The answer by @Tristan Richard is correct, the extra is not there when `onCreate()` is called for the first time.

Comment: Could you write me where to use this method onNewIntent please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On create is only called when activity is launched. It main remain "alive" while receiving your notification. You should therefore have your code handling the extra in:

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if (intent.hasExtra("action")) {
            String action =  intent.getExtras().getString("action");
            // Do what ever is needed
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("gotToFragment1")) { 
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFragment, new Fragment1()).commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Add the `onNewIntent()` method to your MainActivity (the activity receiving the new Intent).
This will be called if your activity is already started.

Comment: Okay, but where I am going to use "goToFragment1"? In this yours method I just using "action"?

Comment: intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1"); is set to late. Set it after intent creation

Comment: I set intent.putExtra like you said after intent creation but nothing. I again receive null pointer, and the most weird thing is that Logcat throws me an error on commented code!

Comment: I done this with onNewIntent but again I am receiving null pointer, and throws me to the line 53 like just before. But, what is the most interesting is that part of code now is commented, but error is still there!

Comment: Try cleaning your project. Seems that you are using Instant run and it has not detected the changes

Comment: Hoh, now I finally can run my app. But how to check whether I have extras or no?

Comment: Check for has extras and get extras

Comment: I dont have option intent.putString..just intent.putExtra

Comment: putString does not exist on intent my bad. Check my update

Comment: So, to summarise: In method sendNotification I must write intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1") or something else?

Comment: Just one more question mate: Why I dont use second part of Intent.putExtra("goToFragment1"),?

Comment: You can! that is the "yourString" variable you can make check before pushing to fragment

Comment: So, I have to write String yourString =  intent.getExtras().getString("goToFragment"); or String goToFragment1=  intent.getExtras().getString("action"); ?

Comment: Thanks mate, I will check now, maybe later, and i will write yo you if it works or not, if you are agree of course.

Comment: Again it backs me to the first page, not to the Fragment1..I don't know why that happens again....

Comment: what do you mean? Is it a different issue?

Comment: Hey, now is all okay! But I have one more problem. Notification brings me to the wanted fragment(Fragment1) butt only when app is in the foreground. But when is in background notification takes me to the first page on MainActivity...I hope that you understand me...

Comment: Well, I have changed your code a litle bit, because that method onNewIntent() wasn't working so I have wrote in OnCreate this: String msg=getIntent().getStringExtra("action");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (msg!=null){
            if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")){
                Fragment1 fragment1=new Fragment1();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

Comment: I think you should call add() instead of replace() at that point

Comment: I have created another question with a code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680025/from-notification-to-fragment-when-app-is-in-the-background

Answer (score 0):

try to move your

```
    intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1");
```

above

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: @Goran_1992 use unique `requestCode` when calling `getActivity`

Comment: I don't know how to use requestCode. Could you help me?

Comment: @Goran_1992 just pass unique `requestCode`, that's all